# React Native White screen with any crash or error iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When I try to launch my project on my macbook I end up with a white screen, without any errors or crashes. I tried it on two other machines, and the same. I have no error messages on XCode and also running on the terminal. I have no error messages on the console (when I activate the "Debug JS Remotly"):

[image: React Native Debugger]
I have of course tried to delete the "node_modules" and `npm install` several times. The application has been running for months on a macbook (one of our developers), we have exactly the same configuration, the same source code (git).
I also tried to change the entrypoint and put something ultra basic like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class BoldAndBeautiful extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
        I am bold
        <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
          and red
        </Text>
      </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

But here it is, when I do a CMD+R several times, the application ends up launching itself and takes me to onBoarding, but it's as if the application had frozen (freeze), I can't click on the buttons, nor scroll, nor call the Shake Gesture popup (The one that allows to activate the debug functions)

I tried on several emulators (iPhone X, iPhone 6s, iPhone 8...) And several different versions (iOs 10, iOs 11, iOs 12)

XCode Version: 10.1
Node Version: v8.11.3
My package.json:

```
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "prop-types": "latest",
    "proxy-polyfill": "^0.3.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "^2.4.3",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.21.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^5.0.3",
    "react-native-flip-toggle-button": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-mail": "^3.0.6",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.0.2425",
    "react-native-offline": "^3.11.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-queue": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-secure-key-store": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-shared-group-preferences": "^1.1.15",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.0.0-rc.5",
    "react-native-wheel-picker": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "realm": "^2.17.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: When running directly from Xcode, does it crash or show any errors on Xcode's console?

Comment: No errors (on xcode console), no crashes whether it's when I launch the project on xcode or by command line (react-native run-ios)

Answer (score 0):

I just found it! All you had to do was use Yarn!
I started the whole installation again using Yarn, here is the diff of yarn.lock:

[image: gitkraken]