# React Native White screen no errors iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

When I tried to launch my project I got a white screen, without any errors or crashes.

Just like [this problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54516297/react-native-white-screen-with-any-crash-or-error-ios), I can't run a project that was running fine! I believe that started to happen after I updated RNN to ^2.27.2 (previously it was ^2.0.2553). But even after going back to previous state with git I still couldn't see the app (same white screen).

XCode Version: 10.3 Node Version: v6.11.2 My package.json:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "card-validator": "^6.2.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "echarts": "^4.1.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.7.1",
    "lodash.compact": "^3.0.1",
    "lodash.every": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.pick": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.values": "^4.3.0",
    "memoize-one": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "native-echarts": "^0.4.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-children-utilities": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-autolink": "^1.8.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-flip-card": "^3.5.5",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.5.2",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.0.2553",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.5",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-webview": "github:caiolv/react-native-webview",
    "react-native-youtube": "^1.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "string-mask": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.2.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3",
    "schedule": "0.4.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```